# Downsampling analytics data in MySQL or in R

Tags: mysql, r, analytics

I am storing analytics data in an MySQL database as a [table with a timestamp and some data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPXYi.png), and want to downsample (i.e group it within a time range) this data (by counting the number of entries) for displaying on an admin console, and I was wondering if it would be more efficient to select the data and downsample it with an R script, or if it would be better to use

```
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV <some time>
```

and do it on the database layer. Any other tips would also be appreciated.

Comment: This would usually be more efficiently done in the database.  Returning all the data incurs overhead for the database (returning lots of data), the transport layer (transporting lots of data), and R (managing lots of data).

Comment: Doesn't `dplyr` have a mysql back-end that does this for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use `dplyr`, you could do it with something like the following:

```
library(dplyr)

yay <- 
  # Specify username and password in my.cnf
  src_mysql(host = "blah.com") %>%
  tbl("some_table") %>%
  # You will need to compute a grouping variable
  mutate(group = unix_timestamp(timestamp)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  # This will return the number of rows in each group
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  # This will execute the query and return a data.frame
  collect
```